# ¿Quién puede explicarme porque el scroll de mi ejemplo se muestra sin los botones para incrementar y decrementar?

Tags: reactjs

Estoy haciendo pruebas con mi scroll, he colocado varios div en bloque de manera que aparezca el scroll, lo que no entiendo es porque mi scroll no muetra los botones normales de incremento y decremento, se que quizas es algo tonto pero he perdido tiempo en esto sin saber porque mi scroll no me muestra en boton superior (el que desplaza la pagina hacia arriba) y el boton inferior (el que desplaza la pagina hacia abajo), no quiero un scroll estilizado, solo quiero el scroll normal de siempre con sus botones. Estoy trabajando en React. Mi codigo es este:

App.css

```
#div1{
  background: turquoise;
  width: 100px;
  height: 200px;
}
#div2{
  background: red;
  width: 100px;
  height: 200px;
}
#div3{
  background: yellow;
  width: 100px;
  height: 200px;
}
#div4{
  background: blue;
  width: 100px;
  height: 200px;
}
```

App.js

```
import './App.css';


function App() {

   
  return (
  
    <div  >

<div id="div1" ></div>
<div id="div2" ></div>
<div id="div3" ></div>
<div id="div4" ></div>
<div id="div5" ></div>

     </div>
    
  );
}

export default App;
```

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: Que sistema operativo y navegador estás utilizando? Esas barras en principio las muestra el navegador, no la página, si esta ocupa más de lo que ocupa la pantalla, el navegador habilita scroll.

Comment: Hola Luis, utilizo google Chrome, si yo se que el scroll lo muestra el navegador, si pruebas el codigo que he colocado te daras cuenta de que la caja de color azul ocupa mas de la pantalla por eso el navegador habilita el scroll como tu dices pero sigo preguntando: Por que el scroll no me muestra el boton superior para subir la pagina y porque no me muestra el boton inferior para bajar la pagina ? Alguien puedo ayudarme a decifrar este enigma ?

Comment: Probé el código y me aparece todo dentro de el viewport sin Scroll, quizás por la resolución de pantalla.. Y si agrando un elemento para generar el scroll, me aparece el scroll perfecto, con ambas flechas/botones... Y mi pregunta que dicho sea de paso no has contestado aun, era porque en windows 7 se instala una extensión de Chrome para recuperar las flechas justamente.. Espero resuelvas tu "enigma".

Comment: Gracias Luis por tu gentileza en intentar ayudarme. Hasta ayer en la noche era imposible salieran los botones, hoy en la mañana enciendo mi pc y todo funciona perfecto, realmente quedara en el pasado como un enigma ya que inclusive ayer en la noche borraba una y optra vez los cookies y no salian los botones, hoy enciendo mi pc y aparecen los botones.

Comment: Jajajaja tu pc tiene personalidad, es cuando ella quiere ... Quedo a las órdenes, hasta la próxima!

Comment: jejeje asi es, cosas extrañas que suceden en el mundo de la programacion, gracias Luis...